# Remove product title when product is "out of stock" on WooCommerce shop and archives pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce, stock

I am running an art gallery website using WooCommerce and the owner does not want to show the product name/title if the product has been sold/out of stock.

I have got this far with putting together a function, but it doesn't work. I wondered if anyone could give me any tips?

```php
// Hides title on Sold products
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'remove_name', 10, 2 );
function remove_name ( $product ) {
    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock()) {
        $title = '';
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Comment: Is it only the title when out of stock? As well, just the shop? what about individual product pages?

Comment: Hi Mark. Thank you very much for commenting and helping me out. It is only the title  (product name) that needs to be hidden when out of stock, in all places except the admin area.

Comment: Hi Kurt, Updated per your comment as it was only getting removed from the shop.

Answer (score 2):

Your code contains some errors and mistakes:

- `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title` is NOT an filter but an action hook
- No arguments are passed to this hook , while your code says there would be 2
- `$product` is undefined, use `global $product;`
- Note: I've added a line with debug information, it can be removed

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title() {
    global $product;
    
    // Is a WC product
    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        // Should be removed but may be useful towards debugging
        echo '<p style="color: red; font-size: 20px;">DEBUG information: ' . $product->get_stock_status() . '</p>';
        
        // NOT in stock
        if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
            // Removes a function from a specified action hook.
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'action_woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 9 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, @7uc1f3r, but this function seems to just repeat the title, as shown in the screenshot: [link](https://snipboard.io/CcGnkp.jpg)

Comment: @Kurt answer updated, after testing with another theme it seems there was an issue with my first answer

Comment: Thanks for trying again @7uc1f3r but this doesn't work. I am using the Peak Shops theme by Fuel Themes, so I don't know if that could be interfering, perhaps? [link](https://kurtt25.sg-host.com/shop/)

Comment: @Kurt It is indeed theme related. If you switch your theme you will see that my answer will work, and i can't really take this into account as there are thousands of different themes. To answer your question, a look at the source code would be necessary, what you can do is look in your theme files for 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' and adjust my answer based on that. Which would equate to changing the number 10 from my answer to the number used by your theme

Comment: Amazing. You're very kind and thanks for your help again. I'll get there one day :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this hook to remove product title. Use this inside the condition to check if product is in stock:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want but still allows access to the product page.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', function() {

    global $product;

    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock()) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
    }

}, 5 );


add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', function() {

    global $product;
    
    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock()) {
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5);
    }

}, 1);
```